# switching the nodes of two user settings in app.config

Tags: c#

I need to switch the nodes of two users settings which are saved in app.config at runtime as renaming the key name is not possible. (nodes under WindowsFormsApplication2.Settings2 to WindowsFormsApplication2.Settings1)

I tried to find a solutions by searching the web and tried to use below code to do that but I get error " object reference not set to instance of object" .

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="WindowsFormsApplication2.Settings2" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="WindowsFormsApplication2.Settings1" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>

        <WindowsFormsApplication2.Settings1>
            <setting name="Label1" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Label1 FrenchName</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Label2" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Label2 French Name</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsApplication2.Settings1>

        <WindowsFormsApplication2.Settings2>
            <setting name="Label1" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Label1 English Name</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Label2" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Label2 English Name</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsApplication2.Settings2>

        <WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Label1" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Test1</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings>

    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Source code:

```
var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
configFile.AppSettings.Settings["Settings1"].Value = configFile.AppSettings.Settings["Settings2"].Value;
```

Comment: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings only applies to the <AppSettings> section of the config file. Is <userSettings> within that section?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see which item that you're trying to access is null (as that's what a `NullReferenceException` is all about)?

Comment: @EvanFrisch, Thanks for your note, No its not part of the AppSettings but there was not such a command for reading configfile.usersettings, I will update the latest app.config now.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet, the appsettings is null, I don't insist in using my code if you have other recommendation

Comment: I would take a look at [ConnectionManager.GetSection()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection(v=vs.110).aspx). It looks like you may be able to get the section by name but I don't know how you would look at the elements within. Hope this helps though.

Comment: Did you also inspect the other properties of the `configFile` object, such as `Sections` and `SectionGroups`?